# Quicksort implementation seems too slow with large data

Tags: java, performance, sorting, quick-sort

I've written a program to compare different sorting algorithms with the array size being 10, 1,000, 100,000, 1,000,000 and 10,000,000. I, of course, expect Insertion to win out on 10 and merge heap and quick to really perform at the upper levels.

However, below are the times I'm getting. (Note that quick sort is growing much faster than heap and merge even though they are all \$\theta(n \log n)\$.)

Things I've considered:

- Each algorithm uses the same seed to initialize each array, so the numbers are the same.
- I am only timing the algorithm and nothing extra.
- My professor approves of the code and doesn't know what's wrong, but maybe we're both missing something.
- I moved the program from my flash drive to the desktop to test possible data transfer problems.
- The algorithm (except for test 2) has only run at night with nothing else going.

```
Key: Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds:Microseconds
```

Test 3

> ```
> n        Insertion        Merge            Heap             Quick            
> 10       0:0:0:0:3        0:0:0:0:28       0:0:0:0:35       0:0:0:0:43       
> 1000     0:0:0:11:470     0:0:0:2:358      0:0:0:7:787      0:0:0:3:596      
> 100000   0:0:1:911:865    0:0:0:51:506     0:0:0:24:257     0:0:0:55:519     
> 1000000  0:3:59:769:105   0:0:0:351:129    0:0:0:238:878    0:0:0:916:885    
> 10000000 8:11:44:552:820  0:0:3:521:108    0:0:3:560:178    0:1:13:709:830
> ```

Test 2

> ```
> n              Insertion      Merge          Heap           Quick          
> 10             0:0:0:0:5      0:0:0:0:49     0:0:0:0:37     0:0:0:0:50     
> 1000           0:0:0:15:473   0:0:0:2:893    0:0:0:8:402    0:0:0:5:230    
> 100000         0:0:2:518:566  0:0:0:57:845   0:0:0:32:917   0:0:0:71:243   
> 1000000        0:5:38:538:795 0:0:0:460:796  0:0:0:312:66   0:0:1:398:508  
> 10000000       11:48:6:630:6390:0:3:690:329  0:0:3:518:281  0:1:18:180:11
> ```

Test 1

> ```
>          n    Insertion        Merge         Heap        Quick
>        10       2676ns      19626ns      26316ns      33454ns
>      1000   11504040ns    2298935ns    6835250ns    3741456ns
>    100000 1849274815ns   47654052ns   23620952ns   52819295ns
>   1000000     0:3:58ns      0:0:0ns      0:0:0ns      0:0:0ns
>  10000000    8:10:25ns      0:0:3ns      0:0:3ns     0:1:15ns
> ```

Here's my quick sort implementation (35 lines):

```java
public static long quick(int[] list) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    quickSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    return endTime - startTime;
}

public static void quickSort(int[] A, int p, int r) {
    if(p < r) {
        int q = randomizedPartition(A, p, r);
        quickSort(A, p, q-1);
        quickSort(A, q+1, r);
    }
}

public static int randomizedPartition(int[] A, int p, int r) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int i = random.nextInt((r-p)+1)+p;
    swap(A,r,i);
    return partition(A,p,r);
}

public static int partition(int[] A, int p, int r) {
    int x = A[r];
    int i = p-1;
     for(int j = p; j < r; j++) {
        if(A[j] <= x) {
            i++;
            swap(A, i, j);
        }
    }
    swap(A, i+1, r);
    return i+1;
}
```

And if needed (267 lines) here's my entire code:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.io.*;

public class algComp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    driver(10); // Sort array of length 10
    driver(1_000); // Sort array of length 1000
    driver(100_000);

    /* WARNING: Running program with the below values takes a lot of time!! */
    driver(1_000_000);
    //driver(10_000_000);
    /* You are now leaving the danger zone. */

    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
    content = String.format(content + "\nKey: Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds:Microseconds");
    printToFile(); // Prints data to times.txt
}

public static void driver(int n) {

    // Insertion sort
    int[] list = data(n);
    if(n == 10) {
        System.out.format("%10s","Unsorted: ");
        printList(list);
    }
    long iTime = insertion(list);
    if(n == 10) {
        System.out.format("%10s","iSorted: ");
        printList(list);
    }

    // Merge sort
    list = data(n);
    long mTime = mergeSort(list);
    if(n == 10) {
        System.out.format("%10s","mSorted: ");
        printList(list);
    }

    // Heap sort
    list=data(n);
    long hTime = heap(list);
    if(n == 10) {
        System.out.format("%10s","hSorted: ");
        printList(list);
    }

    // Quick sort
    list=data(n);
    long qTime = quick(list);
    if(n == 10) {
        System.out.format("%10s","qSorted: ");
        printList(list);
    }

    if(n == 10) { // This will only print once
        // Print prettifying stuff
        System.out.println("Data is being written to times.txt...");
        content = String.format(content + "%-9s%-17s%-17s%-17s%-17s\n",
            "n","Insertion","Merge","Heap","Quick");
    }

    content = String.format(content + "%-9d%-17s%-17s%-17s%-17s%-1s",n,displayTime(iTime),
    displayTime(mTime),displayTime(hTime),displayTime(qTime),"\n");
}

public static long insertion(int[] A) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int i, j, key;
    for(j = 1; j < A.length; j++) {
        key = A[j];
        // If previous is greater than selected (key) swap
        for(i = j - 1; (i >= 0) && (A[i] > key); i--) {
            A[i+1] = A[i];
        }
        A[i+1] = key;
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    return endTime - startTime;
}

public static long mergeSort(int[] A) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    if(A.length > 1) {
        // First Half
        int[] firstHalf = new int[A.length/2];
        System.arraycopy(A, 0, firstHalf, 0, A.length/2);
        mergeSort(firstHalf);

        // Second Half
        int secondHalfLength = A.length - A.length/2;
        int[] secondHalf = new int[secondHalfLength];
        System.arraycopy(A, A.length/2, secondHalf, 0, secondHalfLength);
        mergeSort(secondHalf);

        // Merge two arrays
        merge(firstHalf,secondHalf,A);
    }

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    return endTime - startTime;
}

public static void merge(int[] A1, int[] A2, int[] temp) {
    int current1 = 0; // Current index in list 1
    int current2 = 0; // Current index in list 2
    int current3 = 0; // Current index in temp

    // Compares elemets in A1 and A2 and sorts them
    while(current1 < A1.length && current2 < A2.length) {
        if(A1[current1] < A2[current2])
            temp[current3++] = A1[current1++];
        else
            temp[current3++] = A2[current2++];
    }

    // Merge two arrays into temp
    while(current1 < A1.length)
        temp[current3++] = A1[current1++];

    while(current2 < A2.length)
        temp[current3++] = A2[current2++];
}

public static long heap(int[] A) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int temp;

    int heapSize = A.length-1;
    buildMaxHeap(A);
    for(int i = A.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
        swap(A,0,i); // Root is now biggest element, swap to end of array
        heapSize--; // Reduce heapSize to ignore sorted elements
        maxHeapify(A,0,heapSize);
    }


    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    return endTime - startTime;
}

public static void buildMaxHeap(int[] A) {
    int heapSize = A.length-1;
    // Bottom up, check parents children, sort and move up tree
    for(int i = (heapSize/2); i >= 0; i--)
        maxHeapify(A,i,heapSize);
}

public static void maxHeapify(int[] A, int i, int heapSize) {
    int temp,largest;
    int l = left(i); // 2i
    int r = right(i); // 2i + 1

    if(l <= heapSize && A[l] > A[i]) // Check left child (which is largest?)
        largest = l;
    else largest = i;
    if(r <= heapSize && A[r] > A[largest]) // Check right child
        largest = r;
    if(largest != i) { // If parent is biggest do nothing, else make parent largest
        swap(A,i,largest);
        maxHeapify(A,largest,heapSize);
    }
}

public static int left(int i) {
    return 2*i;
}

public static int right(int i) {
    return 2*i+1;
}

public static long quick(int[] list) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    quickSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    return endTime - startTime;
}

public static void quickSort(int[] A, int p, int r) {
    if(p < r) {
        int q = randomizedPartition(A, p, r);
        quickSort(A, p, q-1);
        quickSort(A, q+1, r);
    }
}

public static int randomizedPartition(int[] A, int p, int r) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int i = random.nextInt((r-p)+1)+p;
    swap(A,r,i);
    return partition(A,p,r);
}

public static int partition(int[] A, int p, int r) {
    int x = A[r];
    int i = p-1;
    for(int j = p; j < r; j++) {
        if(A[j] <= x) {
            i++;
            swap(A, i, j);
        }
    }
    swap(A, i+1, r);
    return i+1;
}

public static void swap(int[] list, int i, int j) {
    int temp = list[i];
    list[i] = list[j];
    list[j] = temp;
}

public static String displayTime(long n) {
    long hours = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toHours(n);
    long minutes = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMinutes(n) - (TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toHours(n)*60);
    long seconds = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(n) - (TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMinutes(n) *60);
    long milliseconds = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(n) - (TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(n)*1000);
    long microseconds = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros(n) - (TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(n)*1000);
    String displayThis = (hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + milliseconds + ":" + microseconds);
    return displayThis;
}

public static int[] data(int n) {
    Random random = new Random(seed); // Random seed stays same for all sorts
    int[] list = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i] = random.nextInt(1000);
    }

    return list;
}

public static void printList(int[] list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.format("%5d",list[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void printToFile() {
    // Print to file
    try {
        File file = new File("times.txt");
        if(!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("Done.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Global variables
public static String content = ""; // Used to print data to text file times.txt
public static int seed = (int)(Math.random()*10_000); // Seed for generating lists
}
```

What do you think? Surely quick sort should be running near 3 seconds at 10mil rather than a minute. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I like that you've included your entire code, +1! Expect the whole thing to get reviewed ;)

Comment: @Mats Mug Thanks, I appreciate any review although I'm most concerned as to why I'm getting unexpected output. Looking forward to any ideas. ;)

Comment: @mjolka This is standard implementation. I'll try what you say later but I'm not sure how you could get SO. Any ideas where its coming from?

Comment: I'll play with it tomorrow (early day), but using my code as is causes no errors.

Comment: Updated my answer with explanation of why it's slow.

Comment: Jumps in running time as input data grows can be caused by issues with the memory hierarchy. Once data outgrow a cache level execution can slow down significantly as data spills over to the next level. The typical hierarchy would be L1 cache, L2 cache, L3 cache, main memory, swap. The jump from main memory to swap can slow some algorithms down by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Not sure why you do this, but it would be interesting to see results for `Arrays.sort()` included (Java switched from Quicksort to Timsort at some time in Java 7). Also, if you are interested in different sorting algorithms, you should have a look at timsort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

Comment: @Axel Java uses double quicksort from its libraries.

Comment: @Ethan: Yes, I missed that they use different implementations for objects and primitives (the distinction seems to be made because quicksort isn't stable which makes no difference for primitives).

Comment: Your basic assumption is *false*. Quicksort is O(n^2) **not** O(nlog(n)) in the worst case. It is O(nlog(n)) in the average case, so, given that the professor told you that the program is correct it must mean that... your inputs cannot be considered "average" for quicksort. And in fact all the analysis you generally do in algorithm classes start saying "assume x_0, ..., x_n are *distinct* integers" and then you analyze the complexity of some sorting algorithm for x_0,..., x_n. Allowing equal elements *can* make a difference for a certain algorithm.

Comment: @Bakuri \Theta is average case. I never mentioned worst case. Worst case shows up with already sorted data, hence the solution.

Comment: Yes you did when you said that "they are all O(nlog(n))". Whenever you don't specifically mention what you mean O-notation means worst case. Anyway my point was the following: Assume that the program is correct (as stated by your professor) and that your input is an average case. The timings you have seen aren't consistent with an O(nlog(n))-on-average  algorithm hence either 1) the program is incorrect or 2) the input is not average. If you have faith in your professor you can disregard option 1 and this leaves option 2. And it seems like your professor was right.

Comment: @Bakuriu Look at the original post, do you see  any mention of BigO? You're wrong to bring that up and what you're talking about with average data is mentioned in both answers below.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Asymptotic_Notation#Theta_Notation

Comment: FYI I'm typing O because typing \Theta takes a huge amount of effort to type in comparison. What you are saying is completely irrelevant to my comment. In fact O(nlog(n)) is "better" than \Theta(nlog(n)) so it doesn't invalidate anything. What I wanted to point out is that you didn't even need *any* knowledge about the algorithm itself to discover where the problem was.

Comment: @Bakuriu O(nlgn) is NOT necessarily better than Theta(nlgn), Heap and Merge are both O(nlgn) yet QuickSort is faster at 10 million. I'm not responding to your stuff any further, especially when you're going to move the goal posts for yourself.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

@mjolka was able to identify the root problem before I was ;-) There are two issues in addition to what he has pointed out.

The first is that it is very bad form to create new Random instances on each partitioning. Random instances internally synchronize on some logic structures, and cause a lot of overhead in their creation. You should instead have a different mechanism for the partitioning.

Additionally, your naming is horrible:

- your class name starts with a lower-case
- your variables are 1-letter long and some are upper-case (`A`, `p`, `q`, `r`, ...).

So, I did a few tests with your code, except I changed the data generator to:

```
public static int[] data(int n) {
    Random random = new Random(seed); // Random seed stays same for all sorts
    int[] list = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i] = random.nextInt(list.length * 10);
    }

    return list;
}
```

When I ran yur code with this, I got the results:

```
n        Insertion        Merge            Heap             Quick            
10       0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:34   
1000     0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:2:480  
100000   0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:21:987 
1000000  0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:139:194
10000000 0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:1:468:183
```

As a result, you don't run in to the duplicate data issue quite as much, and the sort is fast.

Then I removed the `new Random()` from the random partition, and just used the mid-value, and he results are:

```
n        Insertion        Merge            Heap             Quick        
10       0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:17   
1000     0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:708  
100000   0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:18:462 
1000000  0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:103:790
10000000 0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:1:182:385
```

Finally, I implemented my own sort using the equals-value grouping, and turned the data back to limit it to 1000, and the results are:

```
n        Insertion        Merge            Heap             Quick            Monkey           
10       0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:16       0:0:0:0:9        
1000     0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:562      0:0:0:0:684      
100000   0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:16:675     0:0:0:18:119     
1000000  0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:532:437    0:0:0:65:608     
10000000 0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:48:533:774   0:0:0:694:184
```

With more random data the monkey sort slows down, and the quick-sort speeds up:

```
n        Insertion        Merge            Heap             Quick            Monkey           
10       0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:16       0:0:0:0:8        
1000     0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:631      0:0:0:0:819      
100000   0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:16:834     0:0:0:22:353     
1000000  0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:103:699    0:0:0:127:421    
10000000 0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:0        0:0:1:223:673    0:0:1:372:614
```

Bottom line is that even with good data, 20% of your time is going to creating new Random instances. I have been using the randomizePartition method:

```
public static int randomizedPartition(int[] data, int first, int last) {
    // Random random = new Random();
    // int i = random.nextInt((last-first)+1)+first;
    swap(data,last,first + (last - first)/2);
    return partition(data,first,last);
```

Then, if you are interested in the monkey sort:

```
public static long monkey(int[] list) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    monkeySort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
    return System.nanoTime() - startTime;
}

private static void monkeySort(final int[] data, final int left, final int right) {

    if (left >= right) {
        return;
    }

    // partition in this method because we need two outputs, the 'same' and the 'lft'.
    // swap values the same as the partition to the end as well.
    final int val = data[right];
    int lft = left;
    int rht = right - 1;
    int same = right;
    while (lft <= rht) {
        if (data[lft] > val) {
            swap(data, lft, rht);
            rht--;
        } else if (data[rht] == val) {
            same--;
            swap(data, rht, same);
            rht--;
        } else {
            lft++;
        }
    }

    // move all the 'same' values in to the pivot point.
    int ntop = lft - 1;
    while (same <= right) {
        swap(data, lft++, same++);
    }
    monkeySort(data, left, ntop);
    monkeySort(data, lft, right);

}
```

**More Detail on Random()**

I made a reference to Random, and it is worth understanding more about what I mean. This is the (slightly reorganized) source code for [java.util.Random](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Random.java#Random.%3Cinit%3E%28%29):

```
private static final AtomicLong seedUniquifier
    = new AtomicLong(8682522807148012L);

public Random() {
    this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
}

private static long seedUniquifier() {
    // L'Ecuyer, "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators of
    // Different Sizes and Good Lattice Structure", 1999
    for (;;) {
        long current = seedUniquifier.get();
        long next = current * 181783497276652981L;
        if (seedUniquifier.compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}

public Random(long seed) {
    if (getClass() == Random.class)
        this.seed = new AtomicLong(initialScramble(seed));
    else {
        // subclass might have overriden setSeed
        this.seed = new AtomicLong();
        setSeed(seed);
    }
}
```

Notice that there is a static AtomicLong called `seedUniquifier`. Every time you create a new `Random`, two references are made to that AtomicLong, causing a number of memory effects that are unnecessary. Additionally, there is a potential race condition in there which may cause the process to loop and retry.

It is already somewhat bad that Random has a single AtomicLong reference to ensure that the Random class is thread safe, but the entire Random constructor is globally safe too essentially (you effectively cannot create two Random instances at the same time, with the same seed). The implementation of that requirement is... costly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with your last point. Are you saying you took away randomization completely and went with normal quicksort? If this is the case, I agree it might be better to a small degree because we can already assume the data is random enough to not need it.

Comment: The point about the random is that you should not be creating a new one each partition. If you can pass an instance around in your stack then that would be a better solution. `new Random()` should be used very sparingly.

Comment: *I removed the `new Random()` from the random `partition()`* to go on and throw out the baby with the bath water, eliminating `random.nextInt()`. An alternative would be to actually instantiate a `QuickSorter` and use a `Random` data member.

Answer (score 37):

This implementation of Quicksort has poor performance for arrays with many [repeated elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements). From Wikipedia, emphasis mine

> With a partitioning algorithm such as the one described above (even
>   with one that chooses good pivot values), quicksort exhibits poor
>   performance for inputs that contain many repeated elements. The
>   problem is clearly apparent when all the input elements are equal: at
>   each recursion, the left partition is empty (no input values are less
>   than the pivot), and the right partition has only decreased by one
>   element (the pivot is removed). Consequently, *the algorithm takes
>   quadratic time to sort an array of equal values*.
>
> To solve this quicksort equivalent of the Dutch national flag problem, an alternative linear-time partition routine can be used that separates the values into three groups: values less than the pivot, values equal to the pivot, and values greater than the pivot.

You can see this quadratic behaviour by running it on the input `new int[10000]`, for example. In fact, you'll most likely get a `StackOverflowError`.

Now in your test data, you have \$10{,}000{,}000\$ elements, but you're only picking random values in the range \$[0,1{,}000)\$. So... you have lots of repeated elements!

Let's run it as-is on my computer (I didn't run insertion sort, as it's too slow)

```
$ java AlgComp && cat times.txt
Unsorted:   323  653  751   33  350  378  913  280  243  792
 mSorted:    33  243  280  323  350  378  653  751  792  913
 hSorted:    33  243  280  323  350  378  653  751  792  913
 qSorted:    33  243  280  323  350  378  653  751  792  913
Data is being written to times.txt...
-----------------------------------------------
Done.
n        Insertion        Merge            Heap             Quick
10       0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:27       0:0:0:0:35       0:0:0:0:38
1000     0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:1:852      0:0:0:0:822      0:0:0:3:224
100000   0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:28:421     0:0:0:20:784     0:0:0:37:872
1000000  0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:233:576    0:0:0:202:443    0:0:0:905:65
10000000 0:0:0:0:0        0:0:2:359:261    0:0:2:752:239    0:1:20:914:310
```

Now let's change this one line in `data`:

> ```
> list[i] = random.nextInt(1000);
> ```

to this

```
list[i] = random.nextInt(1000000);
```

Now the results are more in line with our expectations:

```
$ java AlgComp && cat times.txt
Unsorted: 1662389001535502665295332468356126461089888942823562420254
 mSorted: 2356224683166238420254529533550266561264610898889428900153
 hSorted: 2356224683166238420254529533550266561264610898889428900153
 qSorted: 2356224683166238420254529533550266561264610898889428900153
Data is being written to times.txt...
-----------------------------------------------
Done.
n        Insertion        Merge            Heap             Quick
10       0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:0:21       0:0:0:0:98       0:0:0:0:56
1000     0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:1:997      0:0:0:1:14       0:0:0:2:41
100000   0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:27:223     0:0:0:22:562     0:0:0:21:587
1000000  0:0:0:0:0        0:0:0:283:939    0:0:0:215:551    0:0:0:137:658
10000000 0:0:0:0:0        0:0:2:899:176    0:0:3:681:388    0:0:1:845:255
```

Of course the real fix is not to change `data`, but to change the partitioning algorithm.

Comment: You know what? I brought this up in class when we were talking about it (apparently I'm the only one whose finished the program. :( ) and my professor said it shouldn't be an issue. XD

Comment: BTW, I realize there's a problem with declaring a new Random object (from folfl's answer) but I still do not get any errors with your solution or anything else. Not sure if you're rewriting anything, but I've run the thing 100 times without issue.

Anyway, I appreciate the answer, this is working fine. :)

Comment: @Ethan Please look here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements)

Comment: I purged a bunch of comments from here which were distractions.